# Save a Spring Data Rest JPA entity in a custom controller and return a HAL representation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

In my Spring Boot web application I have a JPA entity `Medium` that records information about uploaded files.

I have a basic Spring Data Rest repository to handle the generic operations:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "/media")
public interface MediumRepository extends CrudRepository<Medium, Long> {
}
```

However, I need the client to upload a file using HTTP multipart upload, then create a `Medium` record and return it in the response. The structure of the response should be the same as calling `repository.save()`. What I cannot figure out is how to have the HATEOAS metadata added. Obviously, if I just return

```
return mediumRepository.save(medium);
```

it will return a basic JSON representation of the entity, no HATEOAS. I [already learned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31782016/466738) that I should probably use a `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler`.

So, my current controller code is:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/upload")
public class MediaEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private MediumRepository mediumRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = POST)
    public PersistentEntityResource uploadMedium(
            @RequestPart MultipartFile data,
            PersistentEntityResourceAssembler persistentEntityResourceAssembler) {

        Medium medium = new Medium();
        // setup of the medium instance
        Medium savedMedium = mediumRepository.save(medium);
        return persistentEntityResourceAssembler.toResource(savedMedium);
    }
}
```

However, I cannot get the `persistentEntityResourceAssembler` injected into the method - I'm getting

```
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.<init>()
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [Cepr0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43982059/466738), I changed my controller to a `@RepositoryRestController`, but I got an exception

```
Circular view path [upload]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/upload] again.
Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view,
due to default view name generation.)
```

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33719903/466738) that `RepositoryRestController`s are not annotated with `@ResponseBody` and should return a `ResponseEntity`, so I changed my code to the following:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/upload")
public class MediaEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private MediumRepository mediumRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = POST)
    public ResponseEntity<PersistentEntityResource> uploadMedium(
            @RequestPart MultipartFile data,
            PersistentEntityResourceAssembler persistentEntityResourceAssembler) {

        Medium medium = new Medium();
        // setup of the medium instance
        Medium savedMedium = mediumRepository.save(medium);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(persistentEntityResourceAssembler.toResource(savedMedium));
    }
}
```

This gives me a nice JSON response with HATEOAS metadata.

Alternatively, annotating the method or the controller with `@ResponseBody` works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [@RepositoryRestController](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers) instead of @RestController.

Comment: This prodded me in the right direction, thanks. I had to make some other adjustments, see my own answer